# Setting JButton action changes the size of the button?

Tags: java, swing, ssh, jbutton, actionlistener

Trying to set up the UI using Netbeans' visual UI builder, but I want to add the action Listeners and action Events at a later time; After all components have been initialized. Strangely, all buttons are sized properly until I add an action listener to them. Notice the buttons that have abnormal height? Those are the ones I added action events to. The code for this can be found [HERE](http://pastebin.com/uDNE0A2D). I want the images to maintain their original height before and after adding the actions.
[image: Notice the buttons that have abnormal height.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Changing

```
btnEditCancel.setAction(new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jpEditSavedLogins.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

To

```
btnEditCancel.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jpEditSavedLogins.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Seems to solve the issue.

Comment: A button may have multiple action listeners, but only one `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods of container, which holds your buttons after you've set the actions to your buttons.

Comment: What will that help? as far as I know that is only for if a component changes in size/components are added to or removed from a container.... as for being better I dont think so, best way to add `Action` is via `addActionListener(...)`